# xna charge power on how long the key is pressed

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am currently working on shooting game. In that I that number of shoot is fix. But I like to make it variable based on how long someone pressed the keyboard key. More power should be generated if key is pressed for longer.

Here is my code.

```
        {
            // Create projectile
            worldEntities.Add(new Sphere(GraphicsDevice, 0.1f, 0.2f, Character.EyePosition() + Character.LookTowards(), 0.8f, Color.Blue));
            // Add gravity to projectile
            (worldEntities[worldEntities.Count - 1] as RigidBody).Acceleration = new Vector3(0f, -10f, 0f);

            // Calculate launch velocity
            Vector3 launchVelocity = Character.LookTowards() * 10f;


            // Set particle velocity to launch velocity
            (worldEntities[worldEntities.Count - 1] as RigidBody).Velocity = launchVelocity;

            // Reset timer
            timer = 1f;
        }
```

Comment: Where's the problem? Save the time when the key was pressed and on release calculate the difference to the current time. Multiply the velocity with this difference and a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a variable for your power multiplier, this will cause your velocity to be 0% at first press, and 100% when it has been held down for the maximum time

```
float power;
const float maxTime = 1000; //1 second
```

In your update method you will need to check is the key is pressed and add the elapsed time since the last frame.

```
if (KeyBoard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    power += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

We will also need to check if the power has reached the max power, and shoot it.

```
if (power >= maxTime)
    //Fire!
```

Also, another case incase the user lets go of the key before it is time to fire. (lastKeyboardState is the last frames state, just set it to KeyBoard.GetState() at the end of each frame)

```
if (lastKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && !currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)
{
//Fire, but without full power
}
```